# Calculation of Feynman amplitude for pseudoscalar coupling: gamma-five matrix calculations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, scattering, feynman-diagrams, dirac-matrices

In the post below I will first state the question, then briefly describe my line of thought and the problem in hand and in the end I will phrase the question again in the light of the description. Anyone can jump right to answering if he believes the answer can be given immediately and just read my working around the problem for comments.

> Question: The question here is:
>
> Is there a way to systematically simplify the calculation of the
>   Feynman invariant amplitude when it is averaged over spins, when the
>   interaction is a pseudoscalar between fermions. That is, is there a
>   systematic way to simplify expressions of the form: $ \sum_{σ i} 
> > [\bar u'_i \gamma ^5 u_i]  $

Doing perturbative calculations on QFT, we connect semantically each Feynman diagramm with an order of the calculation of the invariant Feynman amplitude M. Here, the task is to calculate the tree diagramm of two incoming fermions giving two outcoming fermions via a pseudoscalar coupling of a neutral pion. That is, the interaction Lagrangian reads:

$$L_{ps} = i g_{ps} \bar {\psi} \gamma ^5 \psi \phi ^{ps}  $$.

When one is dealing with a coupling as in QED, he has an interaction Lagrangian like the above but with a difference: the gamma five matrix is replaced by a $ \gamma ^μ $ matrix. This has a result that, when calculating the Feynman invariant amplitude, we can use the Casimir trick to replace all the Dirac  and $ \gamma ^μ $ matrices with traces and simplify automatically the calculations.

With a pseudoscalar interaction like the one I mentioned I have to calculate an amplitude that contains terms of the form like:

$$\bar {u'} \gamma ^5 u $$, where the u is the Dirac spinor for a fermion, $ \bar u = \gamma ^0 u$ and the primed spinor indicates the outcoming fermion while the un-primed the incoming.

Working on Dirac representation means that I know the $\gamma ^5$ matrix and thus I can conduct the calculations. But to get the correct spin- averaged amplitude, I will have to do all the possible calculations for the Dirac spinors- that is with spin up and down. And after all the multiplications I will have to sum over.

> Question: The question here is:
>
> Is there a way to systematically simplify the calculation of the
>   Feynman invariant amplitude when it is averaged over spins, when the
>   interaction is a pseudoscalar between fermions. That is, is there a
>   systematic way to simplify expressions of the form: $ \sum_{σ i} 
> > [\bar u'_i \gamma ^5 u_i]  $

Thank you.

Note: Any comments for verifications or more explanations on my behalf are welcomed. Also any comments with references are welcomed.

Comment: Would you prefer $\gamma^5=\frac{i}{4!}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\beta$?

Comment: @snulty  Hi. Thanks for the relation; I 've seen it earlier today but I cannot see how it would make calculations simpler. That's doe to the fact that I would still have to make all the calculations regarding the summing over spin polarizations of the fermionic Dirac spinors, just not for gamma 5 but for the others. Or am I mistaken? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to sum the amplitude itself over spins? It is much more standard to perform a sum over spins after squaring the amplitude. And then it is immaterial whether the interaction contains $\gamma_\mu$, $\gamma_5$ or $\gamma^\mu\gamma_5$. The process you mention would lead to
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A} \propto \frac{(\bar{u}_2 \gamma_5 u_1)(\bar{u}_1^\prime \gamma_5 u_2^\prime)}{s} - \frac{(\bar{u}_1^\prime \gamma_5 u_1)(\bar{u}_2 \gamma_5 u_2^\prime)}{t}.
\end{align}
The first term in the square is then
\begin{align}
|\mathcal{A}|^2 \biggl |_{s^{-2}} &= \mathrm{Tr} \left [ u_2 \bar{u}_2 \gamma_5 u_1 \bar{u}_1 \gamma_5 \right ] \mathrm{Tr} \left [ u_2^\prime \bar{u}_2^\prime \gamma_5 u_1^\prime \bar{u}_1^\prime \gamma_5 \right ] \\
&\to \mathrm{Tr} \left [ p_2^\mu \gamma_\mu \gamma_5 p_1^\nu \gamma_\nu \gamma_5 \right ] \mathrm{Tr} \left [ p_2^{\prime \rho} \gamma_\rho \gamma_5 p_1^{\prime \sigma} \gamma_\sigma \gamma_5 \right ]
\end{align}
and so on.